# How do I filter insignificant modes from a kernel density estimation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kernel-smoothing, scipy, numpy

How do I detect the number of significant modes in a set of data?  I have a set of 1 dimensional data where the number of modes are unknown.  I'm familiar with python and scikit learn so I use the Kernel Density Estimator module to create a gaussian function of the data.  I detected the maxima and minima by looking at when the slope of the function changes.  The result is....

[image]

As you can see, there are six modes but there are four additional modes that are insignificant.  What is the best way to filter these insignificant modes out?  Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks.